# tableview with black screen

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

I have an application with 3 view. The first is the main menu, the second is this (a list of songs title). I have 800 title to display.
I want to implement a tableview that shows all this title.
When I try to run the build is correct but, when I go to the view of the tableview I see only a black screen on my iPhone. I tried many times and I discovered this: if I delete my app from the iPhone and I tun it for the first time everything goes correctly but if I try to run a second one the screen is black. I tried my iPhone X and the emulator. what's the problem?

My second question is this: is possible to store all my arrays into another file and not in TableViewController? Thanks to everybody.

```
 import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //Creo le sezioni
    let sections = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G",]

    //Creo i vari Array divisi per lettere
    let cantiA: [String] = ["A BRUSA SÜTA ‘L SUSA","A DESTRA DELL’ISONZO","A FERRO FREDDO","A L’È SIRA","A L’OSPEDAL DI GENOVA","A LA MATIN BONURA","A LA MODA D’II MÔNTAGNÔN","A LA TOR VANGA","A MASSAUA","A MEZZANOTTE IN PUNTO","A PLAN CALE IL SORELI","A VAN I BRAVI ALPIN","A’ VAN SISÌLIS","ABANDONO","ABBIAM LE SCARPE GROSSE","ADAMELLO","ADDIO CARA MAMMA","ADDIO MIA BELLA, ADDIO","ADDIO NINETTA","ADESSO DORMI","ADUA","AI COMANDI","AI MORTI PER LA PATRIA","AI PREÂT","AL CJANTE IL GIÂL","AL COLONNELLO TINIVELLA","AL COMANDO DEI NOSTRI UFFICIALI","ALL’ALPINO D’ITALIA","ALL’ARMI, ALL’ARMI BERSAGLIERI","ALLA MATTIN","ALLA MATTINA","ALLA MATTINA SI GH’È ‘L CAFÈ","ALLA PRESA DEL CAVENTO","ALPIN JO MAME","ALPINI","ALPINI DELL’OROBICA","ALPINI IN MONTAGNA","ALPINI MITRAGLIERI","ALPINO DELLA JULIA","ALPINO MIO BELL’ALPINO","ALPINO PARTIGIANO","AMA CHI T’AMA","AMA IL VECCHIO","AMICI MIEI","AMILCARE","AMMORE AMMORE","AN VAL DONDONA","ANCHE MIO PADRE","ANCHE SE PESA","ANCORA ‘STI QUATRO","ANDOUMA PROU","ANDREMO IN FRANCIA","APPENA SUL PASUBIO","APRI LA PORTA","APRILE SENZA UN FIORE","APRITE LE PORTE","ARDA BÈRGHEM","ARSO","ARTIGLIERE","ASCOLTATE AMICI CARI","ATTRAVERSO VALLI E MONTI","AU MONT BLANC","AUGELLIN DI PRIMAVERA","AVE, O VERGINE","AVER ‘NA FIGLIA SOLA SOLETA","AVEVA QUINDICI ANNI","AYAS","AZZURRI MONTI"]

    let cantiB: [String] = ["BALDI E FORTI"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
        print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            // Fruit Section
            return cantiA.count
        case 1:
            // Vegetable Section
            return cantiB.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Create an object of the dynamic cell “PlainCell”
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlainCell", for: indexPath)
        // Depending on the section, fill the textLabel with the relevant text
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            // Fruit Section
            cell.textLabel?.text = cantiA[indexPath.row]
            break
        case 1:
            // Vegetable Section
            cell.textLabel?.text = cantiB[indexPath.row]
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you added delegate-datasource for your `UITableView`?

Comment: I've added a photo to show you that I have added the datasource

Comment: while seeing that black screen, were you able to interact with the app at all?

Comment: no. when I push the button with the Segue to my TableViewControllerScene appears a black background and nothing else. I can't see my back button, my search bar and my tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think your problem is in the first line, where you declare your TableViewController as a subclass of **UIViewController**. Shouldn't it be a subclass of **UITableViewController** to have a *UITableView* to be filled with the data?

you have:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, ...
```

maybe this helps:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
```

Comment: I tried but if I change I get this error: Redundant conformance of 'TableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' and Redundant conformance of 'TableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'.

Comment: If I try to delete the datasource and the delegate I have another problem

Comment: YES, If you declare it as UITableViewController, you don't need to add the protocols, just delete it.

Comment: Check your mainStoryboard. Did you really added a UITableViewController ?

Comment: Thankyou @LukeSideWalker it works!!! how can I add a search bar to filter my list??